# Can I find out easily which questions that I close-voted have subsequently been deleted?

Tags: support

Title says it all really: "Can I find out easily which questions that I close-voted have subsequently been deleted?"

The "meta questions" (IE why I'm asking this question) are "what is it that in practice leads to a question being deleted, and how often does that happen?  Can I see evidence of how that works?"

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/248731

Comment: Related: [Help me make myself a better moderator: give me statistics about my own close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248267)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Not until you're a 10K+ user.

But when you are, they show up under the Votes tab with the same color as all deleted posts on Stack Overflow.

[image]